# How to redirect standard input when debug python?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

When i debugged c code, i always use 'gdb a.out < test' to redirect standard input stream. But when it comes to `pdb`, i found it doesn't work. After searching in pdb help doc, i still can't find something relative to this problem.

EDIT: I post my code. Can you help me change it to read from file with the minimum modification. Thanks.

```
cnt = int(raw_input())
paths = []
for cs in range(cnt):
    action, path = map(None, (raw_input() + " dumb").split(" ", 1))
    if (action == "pwd"):
        print "/",
        for p in paths:
            print p + "/",
        print
    else:
        strs = path.split("/")
        for i in range(len(strs)):
            p = strs[i]
            if (p == ""): 
                continue
            if (p == ".."):
                paths.pop()
            else:
                paths.append(p)
```

Comment: Why do you need to redirect the standard input stream? Perhaps we could help you with the underlying problem instead.

Comment: I am working on some ACM problem. So i need import the test data to my  program.

Comment: Python code is easier to change than to try and make pdb do what you want in this case; just load the input from a file instead of from sys.stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Change your program to read the test data from a file specified on the command line.

Comment: This, although it is what I generally wind up doing, is annoying when debugging scripts that are meant to read from stdin...

Comment: Totally anti Unix soul

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found a solution. So i just need to comment and uncomment these two lines which initial `file` to switch the way `stdin` comes from.

```
import pdb
import sys

file = sys.stdin
#file = open('test', "r")

cnt = int(file.readline())
paths = []
for cs in range(cnt):
    inputs = file.readline().split()
    action  = inputs[0]
    if (action == "pwd"):
        sb = "/"
        for p in paths:
            sb = sb + p + "/"
        print sb
    else:
        path = inputs[1]
        strs = path.split("/")
        for i in range(len(strs)):
            p = strs[i]
            if (p == ""): 
                continue
            if (i == 1 and strs[0] == ""):
                paths = []
                paths.append(p)
                continue
            if (p == ".."):
                paths.pop()
            else:
                paths.append(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an ugly temporary hack you can redefine `raw_input()` (Python 2) or `input()` (Python 3) to read from file like this (for Python 2 replace `input` with `raw_input`)

```
def input(f=open("test")): return f.readline().rstrip()

# `input()` now reads from "test" file instead of STDIN!
... = input()
```